# How to pass value from a listbox to an empty dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `listbox` which contain some string ... and I would like to pass those string to an empty `dropdownlist`? Is it possible? Just the value in the `listbox` will be chosen.

I dont know what I'm doing .. And for this I have to use a for loop which I'm still confused about.

This is my code for now:

```
    string [] lines = new string [cartListBox.Items.Count];
    int select;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length ; i++)
    {
        select = cartListBox.SelectedValue
        watchedMoviesDropDownList.Items.Add(cartListBox.Items.Count.ToString());
    }
```

However, when I debug it, it gives me an error saying that index is out of range... :( Please help....!

Comment: What kind of framework do you use?

Comment: @Gangadhar: why should this be a C++ question? Looks like C# to me.

Comment: looking at keyword new, question seems to me As C++ one rather than C. Now this is clear. the only statement 'string [] lines' which differs here between `C++  and C#`

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to do it, you don't need:

```
string [] lines
```

nor:

```
int select
```

Just use this code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < cartListBox.Items.Count; x++)
    watchedMoviesDropDownList.Items.Add(cartListBox.Items[x]);
```